# OroCrm how to create migrations automatically without coding them

Tags: php, symfony, orocrm

I'm creating my custom entities with OroCrm. I have created my own bundle SmartMedCRMNewBundle.

```
<?php
namespace SmartMed\Bundle\CRMNewBundle;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class SmartMedCRMNewBundle extends Bundle{}
```

After I created under the bundle my own entity CustomEntity

```
<?php
namespace SmartMed\Bundle\CRMNewBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Oro\Bundle\AccountBundle\Entity\Account;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Metadata\Annotation\Config;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Metadata\Annotation\ConfigField;
use Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CustomEntityRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="custom_entity")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class CustomEntity
{
/**attributes**/
}
```

After I created an installer under SmartMed\Bundle\CRMNewBundle\Migrations\Schema using the command `php bin/console oro:migration:dump --bundle=SmartMedCRMNewBundle > SmartMedCRMNewBundleInstaller.php`.

After the successful generation of the installer I executed the command `php bin/console oro:migrations:load --force` and it loaded my installer successfully.

Now when I want to make updates in my entity and my database I found myself obligated to code my own migration responsible for the update.

I want to know if there is an other way to generate automatically these migrations like in doctrine/migrations.

I'm working with OroCrm version 4.2.7

Answer (score 0):

There are no tools OOB for generating versioned migrations. The only available command is oro:migration:dump but it's only suitable for the installer.

Comment: So what is the solution to automate the migration when someone add a new field from UI and other programmatically(inside bundles entities)

Comment: If it's a product attribute - you can use import/export functionality. For other cases, the feature is not implemented. The only way I know to migrate UI changes is manual partial database migration

Comment: https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/products/product-attributes/import-product-attributes/